# How to get rid of cyclic redirection when using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remake references with get parameters in the CNC links, the conversion itself works, but when I click on the link, the page loads for a long time and at the end shows that
*The page is not available
The www.by site has redirected too many times.
Delete cookies ..
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

Here is the code I use

Reference type

sitedotcom/product.php?article=PP454&name=LM78H05K-[TO-3]

Is transformed into
sitedotcom/PP454/LM78H05K-[TO-3].html

Here's how to do this in htpacces:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([^/]*)&name=([^/]*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !url_rewrited=1 
RewriteRule product.php /%1/%2.html? [R,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /product.php\?article=$1&name=$2  [L,NC]
```

Prompt where to dig, so that there is no cyclic redirection

Paul

Comment: Please use english or have a look at the language specific stack overflow page.

Comment: Paul,
Please use English or have a look at the language specific stack overflow page. In addition, https://translate.google.com/ is a great resource for translating your questions into English and reading English responses.

Павел,
Пожалуйста, используйте английский или просмотрите страницу переполнения стека на языке. Кроме того, https://translate.google.com/ - отличный ресурс для перевода ваших вопросов на английский язык и чтения английских ответов.